# JAVA How to change instance fields values without copying new instance reference

Tags: java, field, instance

Let say I have class A

```
public class A {
    private int field1;
    private String field2;
    ...
}
```

I create new Instance of A, then second Instance of A:

```
A a1 = new A();
A a2 = new A();
```

Is there any easy way (reflections or so) to copy fields from `a2` to `a1` without assigning Instance `a2` to `a1` (I don't want to change reference of Instance `a1`, only values of its fields)? I know I can do it manually in some method, but if there are many fields its kinda not practical.

I was thinking if there is maybe some way over reflections ?

Anyone has some experience with it ?

Comment: Do you want to use the same references that a1 has or do you want an deep copy?

Comment: Have you considered defining a copy constructor, or implementing deep copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things that you need to consider and many ways you can do this depending on the requirements.  Using reflection you could to something like this

```
    A a1  //the original a
    A a2 = new A();  //the "duplicate"

    Field[] fields = A.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field f : fields){
        f.setAccessible(true); //need that if the fields are not 
        //accesible i.e private fields
        f.get(a1);
        f.set(a2, f.get(a1));
    }
```

Note that a2 ***is NOT a deep copy*** of a1 but it has asssigned the same references of a1. That means that if your class A has a object field of class B like this

```
    class A { 
          B b;
    }
    class B { 
        public String myString;
    }
```

then after you have created a dublicate a2 , changing the myString of b object will be reflected to both a1 and a2. This happens becuase both a1 and a2 have reference to the same B instance.

Comment: thanks, its working, and I have simple case like described above.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig)
```

See [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html)

Comment: Should fields be somehow annotated ? Because in my case I see no change after calling that `copyProperties` method.

Comment: I read that BeanUtils copy only public fields :(

Comment: Could you try to add public getters/setters?

Comment: I have public getters/setters :(